# How to populate Jinja2 template that is stored in Ansible variable?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am looking for a way to populate Jinja2 templates that are part of the value of the Ansible variable. I have YAML file that looks like below:

```
metadata:
  name: {{ metadata_name }}-prod
  labels:
    app: {{ app_name }}
    env: {{ load_zone }}
```

In my playbook I read the file into a variable `manifest`:

```
name: load file into variable
include_vars:
  file: "/etc/configs/mydata"
  name: manifest
```

Now what I need is a way to replace Jinja2 templates in the `manifest` variable by actual values. For example, given facts that a value of `metadata_name` is "my_app", `app_name` is "My Application" and `load_zone` is "us_east" then 
instead of the `manifest` value which is:

```
metadata:
  name: {{ metadata_name }}-prod
  labels:
    app: {{ app_name }}
    env: {{ load_zone }}
```

I would like to get this value:

```
metadata:
  name: my_app-prod
  labels:
    app: My Application
    env: us_east
```

Can anyone advise about Ansible module or function... or a trick?

Comment: Are those 3 items _static_ or they are computed as the playbook runs? That is: does `load_zone` change over time, or the host starts out in a known `load_zone` and you just need to make that information available to your playbook?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your question. I had edited the question to provide the better example of what i want to achieve. It is safe to assume that the variables in the template always have values.

Comment: ok, then maybe I'm not understanding your question, either: with that `metadata:` business, is that a file that you are reading, a file that you are trying to create, or a `set_fact:` representing a `dict` in your playbook?

Comment: To narrow down the problem, I have a fact that is a dictionary (mapped from a file). Some of the dictionary's values are jinja2 templates. I am looking for a method to evaluate these templates so the dictionary's values will be evaluated jinja2 expressions and not the templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that any evaluation of the variable (fact) using Jinja2 filter will do it. For example, given a dictionary from the question is stored in the variable `manifest` and other variables that are templates in the dictionary's values, the following expression will substitute the variables' values to the dictionary values:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: evaluate dictionary
      set_fact:
        manifest: "{{ manifest }}"
```

Mind that if the variables that are used in templates were undefined, the `undefined` string will be substituted for the values.